# Sitecore Advance System Reporter Graph and Chart Capabilities

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

Can we add charts and graphs using Sitecore advanced system reporter? I had a look and couldn't find any ?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to have reflected in your charts / graphs!?

Comment: I need to display some line graphs with x axis as the time and Y axis as the number of data created during the period.